# Where is documentation about the "parser" methods?

Tags: django

I want to know what this ( and other ) methods does:

parser.compile_filter()

Comment: Where does this method come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only official docs, which I'm sure you found [are here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag).

Other good places to look are, the [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/search?group=django-users&q=compile_filter&qt_g=Search+this+group), the [developer group](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/search?group=django-developers&q=compile_filter&qt_g=Search+this+group), the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/__init__.py), and the [source code history](http://code.djangoproject.com/log/django/trunk/django/template/__init__.py),

As far as `compile_filter` goes.  The source (with a docstring) says.

```
def compile_filter(self, token):
    "Convenient wrapper for FilterExpression"
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
```

And FilterExpression is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/_modules/django/template/base/) as:

> Parses a variable token and its
>   optional filters (all as a single
>   string), and return a list of tuples
>   of the filter name and arguments.
>   Sample:

```
>>> token = 'variable|default:"Default value"|date:"Y-m-d"'
>>> p = Parser('')
>>> fe = FilterExpression(token, p)
>>> len(fe.filters)
2
>>> fe.var
'variable'
```